# Start Jupyter notebook from Ubuntu bash

Tags: bash, scripts, gateway

I'm running a Jupyter Notebook locally on my Ubuntu server. It uses a Datamechanics Gateway.

Starting the bash **manually** works, using

```
jupyter notebook my_notebook.ipynb --gateway-url=$GATEWAY --GatewayClient.auth_token=$TOKEN --GatewayClient.request_timeout=600
```

The bash command connects to gateway, opens Firefox Browser and the notebook starts all cells automatically (with the help of a HTML script)

Now i want to start this bash **automatically** from a cronjob once a day.
I tried redirecting the output to a file and starting Firefox before execution of the bash.
Without success. Notebook doesn't start in Firefox Browser.

Is there a better idea to start a notebook that uses a gateway automatically?

Comment: Cron environment does not have the full path variable. It is better to write out the full path of all the scripts and applications when called from a cron job.

Comment: You might also want to see https://askubuntu.com/a/1334403/231142 as the DISPLAY variable will have to be set before it can launch Firefox.