# xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0

Tags: nvidia, bash, cron, cuda, xserver

I have a cronjob that didn't work this morning. The line in `crontab -e` looks like this:

```
20 9 * * 1-5 export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /opt/ibc/twsstart.sh
```

I couldn't find any errors in `/var/log/syslog`, but when I try to run that command in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
taylor@mean-machine:~$ export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /opt/ibc/twsstart.sh
taylor@mean-machine:~$ xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

Would this have anything to do with me trying to install Nvidia drivers and Cuda last night? That installation gave me trouble and I remember fiddling a lot with adding and removing libraries. I think I remember seeing something about `xserver` in there.

Comment: Might want to see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1334403/231142 as depending on what DM you are using and how you login can determine if DISPLAY is :0 or :1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [@Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance)'s suggestion, somewhere in me messing with things, `DISPLAY` got changed to `:1` from `:0`.