# How to autostart a jar file with swing GUI when booting Ubuntu

Tags: bash, scripts, xorg, java, autostart

I'm trying to autostart a jar file with an .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
java -jar /home/username/Desktop/jarfile.jar
```

The jar file is a Swing GUI application. When i manually start the script, it works perfectly fine. It's an application, that displays a picture on the screen.

I've tried to create a service in systemd that executes, but i get following exception thrown:

```
Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I tested many DISPLAY variables, such as '' or 'localhost:0.0', but nothing worked.

How can i get the DISPLAY variable/ autostart script working?

Comment: It may not be :0 for the display.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1334403/231142

Comment: I removed the `export DISPLAY=:0` and modified the 3rd line to
`startx /usr/bin/java -jar jarfile.jar` and it seems to be working!